# RandomAccessFile writechar method writing NULto file and writeUTF writing ENQ , how to get ridoff those?

Tags: java, file-handling, java-io, randomaccessfile

In **java.io.RandomAccessFile** , when the method **writeChar()** is used to write a char array in loop to a **Text file** as

```
RandomAccessFile txtfile = new RandomAccessFile("Hello.txt","rw");
char c[] = {'S','i','g','n','e','d'};
for(char k:c) txtfile.writeChar(k);
```

Gives a Result in *Hello.txt* as when opened in normal notepad

```
 S i g n e d
```

but , when opened with text Editor *NotePad++* the *Hello.txt* is shown as

```
 [NUL]S[NUL]i[NUL]g[NUL]n[NUL]e[NUL]d
```

and when i used **writeUTF()** method to write a String to *Hello.txt* as

```
txtfile.writeUTF("hello");
```

it given result as  a blank space in front and when opened in NotePad++ it is showing as

```
[ENQ]hello
```

How i can write or append a Normal Line to file with out Spaces(like [NUL] or [ENQ] ) as in this case ?

please post answer **how to write any String to a file in RandomAccessFile in Java** !

**Thanks** in Advance !

Comment: Which file encoding do you want to use? What you describe is the desired behavior if UTF-16 is used as file encoding.

Comment: Yes i got it ,I tried to write a UTF-8 byte in the format  of UTF-16 ! so it given a NUL in front of every char it written!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` value in Java is two bytes. `RandomAccessFile` is meant to read and write binary data.  It does not do any text transformations.  When asked to write a character, it just writes the in-memory representation of that character to disk.

Look at the documentation for the `RandomAccessFile` class:

> writeChar(int v)
>
> - Writes a char to the file as a two-byte value, high byte first.

> writeByte(int v)
>
> - Writes a byte to the file as a one-byte value.

> writeBytes(String s)
>
> - Writes the string to the file as a sequence of bytes.

So use `writeByte` instead of `writeChar` to write a character to the file as a single ASCII byte that all editors should deal with in the same way.
To write a String to the file as single-byte characters in one call, use the `writeBytes` method, which takes a String and writes it to the file as single-byte characters.

If you only want to write text to a file, it's better to use a `FileWriter` or `OutputStreamWriter` class to do so.  These classes write text taking character encoding into account.  The former assumes a default character encoding.  The latter allows you to specify the character encoding you want the class to use to convert text to bytes before writing to the file.